# PostgreSQL -> Groupping by earth_box

Tags: postgresql, gps, psql, earthdistance

Is possible group my entries (contains latitude & longitude values) usgin earth_box to group all by distance (500 meters)!?

Thanks ;)

Comment: what have you done so far?..

Comment: No, that's not possible. Just think of the following example: you have 3 points (a triangle), A, B and C. A and B are 400 meters away from each other as well as B and C. But A and C are 600 meters away from each other. What group should hold B? Which holds the A or the C one (as they should be in distinct groups)? -- The best you can do is to group by a grid (a.k.a. round coordinates to a 400m × 400m grid & group by that).

Comment: I thinked that is not possible too, but I would like see a another opinion about that.

Anyway, thanks! ;)